# Joining / nesting excel if statements in Excel

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

I have three statements:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($ET$2,B2)),B2,CONCATENATE("NA ",B2))
```

But I want to do

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($ET$2 **OR** $ET$3 **OR** $ET$4, B2,CONCATENATE("NA ",B2))
```

how could this be accomplished in Excel?

or could I instead nest these two (which I have tried, but had no luck)

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($ET$2,B2)),B2,CONCATENATE("NA ",B2))
and
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($ET$2,B2)),B2,CONCATENATE("NA ",B3))
```

Comment: Not a programming question. Should be asked at Super User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but that would include an `or` condition in the `if` statement:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($ET$2,B2)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH($ET$3,B2)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH($ET$4,B2))),B2,CONCATENATE("NA ",B2))
```

note: in Excel2003, I am not sure that OR can take more than 2 arguments, in which case you can do `OR(OR(x,y),z)`

Answer (score 1):

To shorten the formula you could use this version

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($ET$2:$ET$4,B2))+0),"","NA ")&B2`

....or even shorter using COUNT but it needs to be "array entered"

`=IF(COUNT(SEARCH($ET$2:$ET$4,B2)),"","NA ")&B2`

Answer (score 0):

Not very readable, but:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(...), ISNUMBER(...),ISNUMBER(...)), B2,CONCATENATE("NA ",B2))
```

should do it.